# Skip a sector but with a different airline

Tags: transit, hidden-city-ticketing

I live in London and want to visit Dubai without paying an arm and a leg for our.
There are flights from Brussels to Dubai via London which are much more appealing to me.
The Brussels to London leg is operated by BA while the London Dubai leg is operated by Virgin.

Can I skip the Brussels London leg and board from London itself?

Comment: Not if it is one ticket, if you skip the first leg, everything else is canceled.